# How can I get the current index value of the foreach loop in php

Tags: php, syntax, foreach

How should I get the current value of the array

```
 foreach ($key1 as $key => $value) {

                            }
```

Here, `$key` represent the current index of an array..
But how do I find the current value of the current index.
Please someone help me..

Comment: Can you please show the data?

Comment: using $value you can get current value

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Can you please elaborate your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP, you can have associative arrays with key => value pairs.

Example:

```
$countryCapitals = ['Germany' => 'Berlin', 'UK' => 'London', 'Netherlands' => 'Amsterdam', 'France' => 'Paris'];
```

When you are iterating with a foreach loop you can access the key value pair as

```
foreach ($countryCapitals as $country => $capital) {
    echo 'The capital of ' . $country . ' is ' . $capital . "\n";
}
```

where the country is the key and the capital is the value.

Answer (score 2):

```
You can get the value from $value; 

foreach ($key1 as $key => $value) {
   echo "Key :". $key ;
   echo "Value :".$value;

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In `$value` you are getting current value of the current index.

**Example:**

```
$yourArr = array('one'=>'first index value','two'=>'second index value');
foreach ($yourArr as $key => $value) {
   echo "Current Index: ". $key. " And Current Value is: ".$value."<br/>";
}
```

**Result:**

```
Current Index: one And Current Value is: first index value
Current Index: two And Current Value is: second index value
```